# Recursion with no arguments

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm needing to create a c++ program which uses recursion with no arguments to calculate the area of a polygon but breaking it into smaller triangles.

My issue is that I don't understand how I'm supposed to create a recursive function when it doesn't call any arguments, unfortunately Google isn't helping me find any information either.

I *think* I've created my base case but not sure where to go next.

```
double Polygon::get_area() const{
   if ((xs.size() <3) || (ys.size() <3)) return 0;
   if ((xs.size() == 3) || (ys.size() == 3))  return ((xs[0]*ys[1] + xs[1]*ys[2] + xs[2]*ys[0]) - ys[0]*xs[1]- ys[1]*xs[2] - ys[2]*xs[0]) / 2;

};
```

Happy to provide further code, however I'm not wanting answers, I'm wanting to understand how to complete the task.

The task states: 
Triangle with corners (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) has area: (x1*y2 + x2*y3 + x3*y1 - y1*x2- y2*x3 - y3*x1) / 2 We can calculate the area of a convex polygon by cutting it up into triangles. The area of each triangle is calculated and summed up to give the area of the polygon. 
Implement get_area() as a recursive function in polygon.cpp. Also implement the member function add() in polygon.cpp.
 We are given a header file:

```
class Polygon {
public:
void add(double x, double y); // add a vertex
double get_area() const; // a recursive function
private:
vector<double> xs; // x-coordinates of the vertices
vector<double> ys; // corresponding y-coordinates
};
```

TIA

Comment: You are paraphrasing the requirements. Since you seem to be confused by them, you can't represent them accurately. Quoting them verbatim first and then adding your thoughts would make this a proper question and less guessing.

Comment: Sorry @UlrichEckhardt, here is the problem: Triangle with corners (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) has area:
(x1*y2 + x2*y3 + x3*y1 - y1*x2- y2*x3 - y3*x1) / 2
We can calculate the area of a convex polygon by cutting it up into triangles. The area of each triangle is calculated and summed up to give the area of the polygon.  Implement get_area() as a recursive function in polygon.cpp. Also implement the member function add() in polygon.cpp.

Comment: Methods have a hidden `this` argument; So it is not really recursion without arguments. Btw, you don't need recursion to compute area, you might use loop instead.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that information, so that it becomes complete. However, it doesn't say anywhere that you are not allowed to use parameters. Hint: While `get_area()` shouldn't require parameters, it doesn't mean that you can't write a private helper function to calculate the area recursively.

Comment: Since it is a member function it actually has one implicit argument, the object itself. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the requirement literally that `double get_area() const` is to be recursive implies that you must have to keep track of the state of your area calculation with a member variable. Furthermore that member variable will have to be marked `mutable` since `get_area` is declared `const`.

It seems to me the simplest approach would be to store the index of the triangle you are currently calculating the area for. This would run from 1 to `xs.size()-2` (for an N-sided convex polygon there are only N-2 non-zero area triangles that you need to get the area of). You don't need to store the intermediate area anywhere as the `return` statement will be of the form `return (area of current triangle) + get_area();`.

Obviously `get_area` will need to increment the (mutable) index of the current triangle. When you get to the last triangle you need to reset the index back to 1 so that the next time it is called it will start afresh. You will also have to stop the recursion by having a separate return statement that does not call `get_area` and just returns the area of the final triangle.

Of course as others have pointed out this is not the most natural way to solve this, a loop would make more sense. I'm not sure if your instructor has carefully worded the requirement to force you to think how to solve this particular technical challenge or if the requirement is not actually as strict as it appears. For example, maybe you've just been taught `mutable` and this is a test to see if you've remembered what you've been taught. It would be nice to know how you get on with this and what the intent of your instructor was.

---

*Edit*

Your comments have indicated that the intent here is to reduce the polygon by one vertex recursively so the idea is to have `get_area` return the area of the triangle involving the first 3 vertices and then create another 'Polygon' object whch omits that first triangle and calling `get_area` on that. The recursion of `get_area` is therefore not within the same `Polygon` instance but instead across a chain of instances. In pseudo-code:

```
Polygon::get_area() const
{
  if ( polygon is a point or line )
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else if ( polygon is a triangle )
  {
    return area of triangle;
  }
  else
  {
    Polygon reducedPolygon;
    Add all vertices apart from the second vertex to reducedPolygon
    return (area of triangle of first three vertices)
         + reducedPolygon.get_area();
  }

}
```

Comment: We've not been taught mutable, nor is it in the textbook. This assignment is all about recursion without helper functions. Quite frustrating as it seems it's not use massively in the industry and I'd rather learn helpful things

Comment: @Sarah: That is odd. The only way to do it recursively (given the class definition you've  been given) without mutable _and_ without helper functions would be to create two new `Polygon` instances within `get_area` that represent each "half" and call their `get_area` methods. This a bit odd since you would still be calculating the same number of triangle areas but with a much higher overhead (think of all the dynamic memory allocation going on creating the vertex vectors).

Comment: actually according to the assignment specs, we're calculating 4 triangles. I'm even more confused now. Starting with (10, 20), (15, 30), (20, 20), area of triangle = 50
The middle node of the triangle (15, 30) is discarded to produce a reduced polygon. Then cut triangle (10, 20), (20, 20), (20, 10), area of triangle = 50
The middle node of the triangle (20, 20) is discarded to produce a reduced polygon. etc etc

Comment: @Sarah: Okay then , it sounds like they _do_ want you to create a new `Polygon` class in `get_area` which has one less vertex each time. Not very efficient but it will work. I hope the instructor will say that this is an inefficient way of solving this particular problem and that it is only meant to be demonstrating the recursion principle.

Comment: @Sarah: You don't initialise `area` so that'll likely be where the massive value comes from. Have a look at the pseudo code I've added to my answer. Hopefully that makes things clearer. You are nearly there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked just for *how to do it?* so, here it is:

- Create a class `Polygon`
- `Polygon` is having a data member as an array of coordinates of polygon.
- Create a private member function which operates on polygon coordinates and returns the area of polygon
- `Polygon` is having public member function `double get_area()`. In `get_area()` call the recursive function to calculate area and return result.

You can see non-recursive implementation [working here](https://ideone.com/mtzl34) and recursive implementation [working here](https://ideone.com/SM1Ce6).

Following is code of non-recursive implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

/**
Class to represent a point in plane
*/
class Point
{
    public:
    int X, Y;
    Point(int x, int y){X = x; Y = y;}
};

class Polygon
{
    //To hold the points
    vector<Point*> coordinates;
    
    public:
    //constructor:
    //  sides - For polygone, side = number of points
    //  points - All points of polygon as (x, y) pair
    Polygon(int sides, int points[][2])
    {
        //Add all points to the vector 'coordinates'
        while(--sides >= 0)
        {
            coordinates.push_back(new Point(points[sides][0], points[sides][1]));
        }
    }
    
    //Helper function to add a point at a latter time with given (x, y)
    void addPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        coordinates.push_back(new Point(x, y)); 
    }
    
    //Helper function to add a point at a latter time with given obect of Point
    void addPoint(Point point)
    {
        coordinates.push_back(new Point(point.X, point.Y)); 
    }
    
    double getArea()
    {
        double area = 0;
        int len = coordinates.size();
        //Fix the point at 0 coordinate
        Point p1 = *coordinates[0];
        while(--len >1)
        {
            //get other 2 points to create traingle
            Point p2 = *coordinates[len];
            Point p3 = *coordinates[len -1];
            area += abs((p1.X*(p2.Y - p3.Y) + p2.X*(p3.Y - p1.Y) + p3.X*(p1.Y - p2.Y))/2.0);
        }
        return area;
    }
    
    ~Polygon()
    {
        //Free dynamically allocated memory
        int len = coordinates.size();
        while(len--)
        {
            delete coordinates[len];
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    int sides[][2] = {{15,15}, {23,30}, {50,25}};
    Polygon p(3, sides);
    cout<<p.getArea()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Approach**: To divide the polygon in to triangle, fix one point and take 2 other points(please refer following image). Add the area of all created triangle.

[image: Image to visualize the approach]

Comment: So I've gotten as far as adding this:     Polygon PolyA;
    PolyA.xs = xs; PolyA.xs.pop_back(); PolyA.ys = ys;  PolyA.ys.pop_back();    Is that on the right track?

Comment: I don't think I'm going to get it, that code just confused me. I think it's time to call it quits for me.

Comment: @Sarah Ok, I added link for recursive implementation and _a bit_ explanation. Hope it will help.